# launch service from different package

Tags: android, service, launch

I trying to make a project, I have one activity and one service from diferent package. The both package I put in one project.

I put the activity in : com.idris.activity, and I put the Service in : com.idris.activity.service

I try to call MyService from a button's listener in  MyActivity like this :

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class);
                 myIntent.putExtra("extraData", "somedata");
                 startService(myIntent);
```

application's manifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="idris.parental.monitor"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MyActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service
            android:name=".MyService"
            android:enabled="true" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

MyService can't launch, what shuld I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this in your manifest:

```
<service
    android:name=".service.MyService"
    android:enabled="true" />
```

Make sure your are using correct `package name` for `service` in `manifest` file. If `MyService.java` file is in `com.idris.activity.service` package than use:

```
<service android:name="com.idris.activity.service.MyService" />
```

Comment: that is not working, 
Error message " 07-18 10:04:06.975: W/ActivityManager(61): Unable to start service Intent { cmp=idris.parental.monitor/.call.CallMonitorService (has extras) }: not found "

Comment: According to your manifest, your `MyActivity` is in `idris.parental.monitor` package not in `com.idris.activity`. What is `CallMonitorService`? See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that u r root pkg name is   **package="idris.parental.monitor"** so u r service class  pkg name must contain these as root path then in manifest u can specify as

for eg

u r service in service pkg.
ie idris.parental.monitor.service

in manifest .service.urservicename