# Service not starting - Manifest Declaration

Tags: android-manifest, android-service

I have an my Application with a button calling the service which is in an associated Library. I when I click the button, both Log statements are shown(the second one shouldn't be if the service were happening I think).

I have Log statements in my onCreate/onStartCommand etc. in the service so I know its not starting the service. I can't think of anything left except that my Manifest isn't correctly made for the service.

Button:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

     Intent service = new Intent(com.test.ServiceNexus.SERVICE);
     Log.e(TAG,"Service Starting");
     startService(service);
     Log.e(TAG,"Service Failed");
}
```

Manifest of Library with service just inside application close node:

```
 <service
            android:enabled="true"
            android:persistent="true"
            android:name="com.andal.ServiceNexus"
            android:process=":ServiceProcess">
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="com.test.ServiceNexus.SERVICE" />
            </intent-filter>
</service>
```

I have a different service that calls a service within the application and that works.
Manifest in Application for that service:

```
<service android:enabled="true" android:name=".MyService"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The manifest needed to be declared inside of my application not inside of the manifest. Also, the name of it needs to include the package of where it came from.

[launch service from different package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11615831/launch-service-from-different-package) helped a bit